# Socket listener in c#

Tags: c#, network-programming, asyncsocket

I want to create a test program about using socket. First i need to write  a simple server program which will listen to the port xxx and retrieve the all streams in different thread to make available to listen other requests(at this point i'm suspicious to be able to get different requests at the same time without moving current request to another port and thread).

What code can make this situation as it is happing real time(client&server will be at the same machine and i think request and answe will be very quickly, thats why i will not be able to see 4-5 requests as they are concurrent requests)?

Comment: Have you looked on MSDN?  For instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

Comment: No. Actually i found this question while travelling and asked. Im sorry because of asking without searching. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RTP library for that here is a nice article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18977/How-to-use-the-managed-RTP-API-classes-in-NET-to-c) to begin

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @reuben's link would be enough but your rtp link is very good to understand deeper and use this for in wide area.